# Single words for denoting a desired number of "a count to be reached" and "the actual number obtained"

Tags: single-word-requests, programming

I'm currently designing a software library. *There are only two hard problems in computer science: Naming things, Cache invalidation and off-by-one errors.*

And at the moment I'm struggling with problem 0: Naming things. The whole thing is for a data collection device. Before the device is started one sets a number of records that shall be collected. While the device is running it can be polled for the number of records obtained so far, or – if a timeout was reached or the process aborted – how many records there are in total.

Now the question is, what (single) words to use for denoting *"this is the number of records that shall be taken"* and what word for *"this is the number of records we have"*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "this is the number of records that shall be taken"

That would be a *target*.

> and what word for "this is the number of records we have"

That would be a *tally*.

Comment: I second "target". Alternatives to "tally" might be "count" (which is what tally means, but may be confusing in computing) or "score".

Comment: @David the target is also a count of sorts though, so *tally* has the advantage of being more clearly a running-count rather than anything else the word *count* can be used for.